# Accessing and summing values of similar keys of dictionary nested in list to make total of i.e. "price" (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, sum, key

This question concerns Python3
I know there are similar topics and similar questions already
but I have been trying to do this for at least 8 hours, scouring solutions on different sites.
I have tried every one and nothing seems to work as desired, even though what I'm trying to do should be quite simple.
I've been looking at it so long I'm starting to confuse myself, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is sum all values of a similar key of dictionaries nested in a list
i.e. summing all the [price] keys to get a total

the dictionary/list is structured as :

```
[
    {
        "Entry1": {
            "date": "",
            "number": "",
            "description": "",
            "Price": "",
            "Tax": "",
            "Total": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "Entry2": {
            "date": "",
            "number": "",
            "description": "",
            "Price": "",
            "Tax": "",
            "Total": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "Entry3": {
            "date": "",
            "number": "",
            "description": "",
            "Price": "",
            "Tax": "",
            "Total": ""
        }
    }
]
```

but whatever I do I can't seem to get it

- I have tried for loops
- tried counter but that counted the amount of characters (maybe because there's also string values in the dict?)
- tried different structures of the dictionary in case I started with the wrong idea
- tried to nest the dictionary in a dict instead of list in case it made it more accessible than list indexes for what I'm trying

probably a simple set of oversight on my part, but I need another set of eyes

Thanks for your time

I would share code but have tried so many different approaches I wouldn't know what to share

Comment: Is the target key (e.g, ```"Price"```) given as an argument?   And by "similar", do you mean identical?

Comment: Yes, i mean identical keys, 
Exactly as specified in my post, the example code, even with the numbered entries

Comment: i have been able to access the value of one list of course,when calling the key of "price "after the listname

but when it's a list with nested dictionaries, as in example
i first of course have to call index, this returns -one key- for example (entry1)

Comment: when trying to use a for loop i can get all [Entries] but i cannot call a key from the [Entries], it either throws an error, or returns every character in vertical fashion, as if using a for loop on a string

i'm probably making an obvious mistake i'm not seeing, but i can't seem to put my finger on it

what i'm trying to do is something like : loop through/read every [Entry] (Entry 1, 2, 3)
from [Entry] return key ["price"]

Comment: and finally: sum(["price"]) for every returned value
to clarify ,when i say price i mean the value associated with the key ["price"]

Comment: There may be a difference between "Price" and "price". (spotted none of the latter in the code snippet, but look at title& "i.e.")

Comment: @greybeard

No, it's not the capital letter, the example i used just happened to be one where i typed it with a capital P  i've been trying for the past few days.  
closest i got was with.   : for entry in provlist.values():  
    for key in entry.items():  
        for subkey in key:  
            if subkey == "price":  
                print(subkey)  

but this prints out "price" for the amount of times it exists in the dictionary, i can't get the value   (for this code i didn't use the [] list brackets in the original example, just the nested dict)

Comment: @Mark Lavin  Update, if you can still spare some time to help me, thanks

Comment: Please state (and tag) a programming language (Python 3?) and show at least *one* implementation attempt as a base for discussion. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where does the data come from? It shows *at least* two levels more than useful.
(Imagine there was a `"name": "Entry2"`attribute.)

Comment: @greybeard   The data is financial data, Invoices to be precise

Comment: @greybeard  
The list is the list of invoices    
every entry (Entry1, 2, 3, ..) is an invoice, seperate documents with identical expected information (number, price,...)    a total of all invoices[prices] should be calculated

Comment: @vcode1 Another question:    The structure of your example is "list of single-key dictionaries of multiple-key dictionaries".   Could you change that to "multiple-key dictionary of multiple-key dictionaries"?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you presented

> ```
> for entry in provlist.values():
>     for key in entry.items():
>         for subkey in key: 
>             if subkey == "price": 
>                 print(subkey)
> ```

In the question, you have shown a `list` of `dict`s of `dict`s -
that would suggest to try (with correct capitalisation of keys…)

```
sum = 0
for prov in provlist:
    for invoice in prov.values():
        sum += invoice["price"]
print(sum)
```

(unless the price is unit price and needs to be multiplied by `invoice["number"]` or replaced by `invoice["Total"]`)